# Recorrer dos listas y eliminar en una basado en la otra

Tags: python

Tengo dos listas en python, una con asignaturas y otra con las respectivas notas de las mismas. Si una nota es mayor que 60, tengo que eliminar la asignatura, o sea, al final, imprimir las asignaturas desaprobadas.El problema es que a medida que voy eliminando, se me van de indice las listas. No encuentro el error ni debugueando. El problema es el iterador, pero no se como hacer q no se vaya de rango

```
asignatures = ["Matemáticas","Física","Química","Historia","Lengua"]
notes = []
for i in range(len(asignatures)):
    notes.append(int(input("Inserte la nota de la asignatura " + asignatures[i] + ": ")))
for i in range(len(asignatures)):``
    if notes[i]>60:
        notes.pop(i)
        asignatures.pop(i)        
print(asignatures[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

En el bucle puedes hacer una copia de la lista original asi `asignatures[:]`  y de esa manera no pierdes el índice.

La parte del código te quedaría así:

```
for i in range(len(asignatures[:])):
    if notes[i]>60:
        asignatures.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya, listo. Lo que sucedia era que estaba eliminando de la lista asignaturas con el mismo iterador que recorria la lista de notas. Lo que debia hacer era, si el iterador de notas aumentaba, y encontraba una nota mayor que 60, eliminar el primer elemento de la lista asignatura.

```
for i in range(len(asignatures)):
    if notes[i]>60:
        asignatures.pop(0)

print(asignatures[:])
```

Answer (score 1):

El pecado es modificar la lista mientras la usas para controlar el ciclo `for`. El valor límite del ciclo se calcula al antes de la primera iteración, y si luego te pones a eliminar elementos, la lista se acorta y terminas accediendo a indices que ya no existen.

Una solución es recorrer la lista en orden inverso, desde el final hacia el principio. En este caso no te afecta cambiar el largo de la lista, pues eso no cambia los primeros elementos.

Para hacer el recorrido cambiamos el rango, para que vaya desde el último indice (`len(asignatures) - 1`) hasta el primero, "incrementando" en -1 en cada ciclo:

```
asignatures = ["Matemáticas","Física","Química","Historia","Lengua"]
notes = []
for i in range(len(asignatures)):
    notes.append(int(input("Inserte la nota de la asignatura " + asignatures[i] + ": ")))

for i in range(len(asignatures)-1,-1,-1):
    if notes[i]>60:
        notes.pop(i)
        asignatures.pop(i)        
print(asignatures[:])
```

produce:

```
Inserte la nota de la asignatura Matemáticas: 10
Inserte la nota de la asignatura Física: 60
Inserte la nota de la asignatura Química: 50
Inserte la nota de la asignatura Historia: 70
Inserte la nota de la asignatura Lengua: 40
['Matemáticas', 'Física', 'Química', 'Lengua']
```